# SSIS Flat File add trailing spaces to columns

Tags: csv, ssis, etl, flat-file, derived-column

I am developing a SSIS package which concatenates 3 columns and then outputs the result to a flat file.

1st column is a emp_number consists of length 10.
The values which I get is `"12345"` or `"123456"` or `"1234567"`.

In the output I want is `"12345     "` or `"123456    "` or `"1234567   "`

I have a requirement wherein I need to have columns of fixed size(10), so if the length a value for a particular column is lesser than 
the expected length I need to pad or fill it with spaces so that the length is matched.

Can you please help.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `Derived Column` transformation that takes the column value, concatenates it to a string made up of 10 spaces (or whatever the total length after padding should be) and then take the rightmost 10 chars using an expression:

```
RIGHT("0000000000" + yourcol, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to iamdave's answer but you need the reverse:

```
left(yourcolumn + "          ",10)
```

There are 10 spaces between the quotes.

if your column is not a string you need to cast it:

```
left((DT_WSTR,10)yourcolumn + "          ",10)
```

Comment: Ha, oops on my part there